Org Agenda Custom View to show only non-repeated tasks
Just what the question says.
Is it possible to build a custom agenda command that shows only tasks without a repeater?
And as a side question, a custom agenda command that shows only tasks with a repeater?

In my workflow, all repeating tasks have the following TODO state: RECURRENT. With this, it is easy to do what you want.

@crocefisso That is a wonderful hack! But how do you set it? I mean the moment the scheduled timestamp gets a repeater, the state automatically changes to RECURRENT?

No, I do it manually. Here are my TODO states:(setq org-todo-keywords '((sequence "INBOX(I)" "BACKLOG(b)" "NEXT(n)" "MEETING(m)" "RECURRENT(r)" "STARTED(s)" "WAITING(w)" "DELEGATED(l)" "|" "DONE(d)" "DEFERRED(f)" "CANCELLED(c)")))
